# C++ Copy_if using lambda

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, lambda, copy

I have an array of `string`s that I want to copy into a `vector` of `string`s **only if** a particular `string`'s length is *equal* to a known value.

```
function(int len){
string lines[8]{
"a string",
"another string",
"and another"
etc..
}
vector<string> v (8);

std::copy_if(lines->begin(), lines->end(), std::back_inserter(v), 
    [len](std::string i) { return len == i.length(); });
```

The errors i get are:

> error C2664: 'bool
>   Grid::SearchGrid::::operator
>   ()(std::string) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'char' to
>   'std::string'
>
> error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'char' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

these are both happening within the `algorithm header` so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. New to these new lambda expressions.

Answer (score 4):

`lines->begin()` and `lines->end()` don't behavior as you expected. `lines` decays to `string*`, then `lines->begin()` will return the iterator on the 1st `std::string` of the array `lines`, and dereference on the iterator would get a `char`.

You could use [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) instead.

```
std::copy_if(std::begin(lines), std::end(lines), std::back_inserter(v), 
    [len](std::string i) { return len == i.length(); });
```

BTW: `vector<string> v (8);` initializes `v` with 8 elements (empty `std::string`s); because you're using `back_inserter` later I think just `vector<string> v;` is enough. Otherwise you'll get 8+ elements in `v` at last.

Other issues: The function return type declaration seems lost; lambda parameter type could be changed to `const std::string&`.

Comment: also really interesting explanation of how the an array or strings would decay

Comment: @euanjones See [Array-to-pointer_decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay) for more informations.